# Get where a 301 URl redirects to

Tags: c#, url, redirect

I have something along the lines of:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/");
webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
HttpStatusCode wRespStatusCode = new HttpStatusCode();

try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    wRespStatusCode = response.StatusCode;
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    wRespStatusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;
}

MessageBox.Show(wRespStatusCode.ToString());
```

which gets the status code of of an HTTP request.

In the case of a 301 "Moved Permanently" response, I was wondering how I might find the new URL that the request is being redirected to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the [301 status code section in the HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2), look into the [`Location`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) header, accessible from the `HttpWebResponse.Headers` property.